# HTML5 video only playing onclick on mobile device (droid chrome mobile)

Tags: javascript, html, video

let's get down to the code:

I'm preparing the document with:
`<video width="300" height="400" id="videoStage"></video><button onclick='video()'>Play video</button>`

as for the JS function:

```
  function video(){
    var vid_url = "https://fbcdn-video-a.akamaihd.net/cfs-ak-ash4/v/82342/969/274169121921_63622.mp4?oh=99ef0d9285cbbd7adf8bc07a845dc0d1&oe=519E400F&__gda__=1369439362_83c7f900e92bdbaa201f49d35a7c144a";
    stage = document.getElementById('videoStage');
    stage.src = vid_url;
    stage.play();
  }
```

working code sample: http://jsbin.com/eviyel/1

this code works just fine and plays the video both on my desktop and my mobile device.
But(!) when the video() function is applied to document.ready - it only plays on my desktop and as for my mobile device it displays empty.

Any solution guys? 10x.

Comment: Update: it seems like autoplay attribute is also not functioning on mobile chrome, as I tried the w3schools demo on my mobile device : http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_autoplay.

any solution guys?!?! it's a must!!!!!!!!!

Comment: it's a deliberate limitation for both Android and iOS devices - the user has to trigger the play on a mobile action. There are some ways to get around it programmatically but there's no guarantee

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself:

Mobile browsers (such as chrome mobile and iOs's) must have a valid 'click' first to enable both video+audio playback.
Once that click as been achieved, the element that was used to play the video/audio is now playable.
You can now change the SRC of that element to play any new media source programmatically without having to click on the DOM once again.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from iOS 10 autoplaying videos that are muted is allowed without user interaction:

https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

Android still seems to require user interaction, although it might be possible to use a touchend event from scrolling the page to start the video playback.